# Time limit error in 'The Minion Game' using python in Hacker Rank

Tags: python, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded

This is the question  [link](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/the-minion-game/problem?isFullScreen=true)  for the quick reference.

> **Problem** :
> There are two players Kevin and Stuart have to play a game in which they're pleased to create multiple strings and will get +1 score for each sub string for which Kevin would select the sub string starting from **vowels** and Stuart will select for **consonants** only.
>
> **Input** :
> String in capital
>
> **Output** :
> Winner name and their score separated with space
>
> **Note :**
> length of string should varies from 0 to 10^6

this is my code given below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def minion_game(string):
    # Verification of basic functionalty
    for character in string:
        if 0<=ord(character)<65 or 90<ord(character)<=255 or len(string)>10**6:
            return None
    # list of vowels and consonant
    vowel=[]
    consonant=[]
    for num in range(65,91,1):
        if num == 65 or num == 69 or num == 73 or num == 79 or num == 85:
            vowel.extend(chr(num))
        else:
            consonant.extend(chr(num))
    #Test string
    #print(''.join(vowel) + '\n' + ''.join(consonant))
    score={'Stuart' : 0, 'Kevin' : 0}
    for iteration in range(1,len(string)+1):
        count= iteration
        for index in range(0,len(string)):
            if count<=len(string):
                char = string[index:count]
                count+=1
                #Check for one character
                if len(char)==1:
                    if char[0] in vowel:
                        score['Kevin']+=1
                    elif char[0] in consonant:
                        score['Stuart']+=1
                #Check for sub string
                else:
                    #logic goes here
                    temp_string = string
                    if char[0] in vowel:
                        #logic goes here
                        for i in range(len(temp_string)):
                            if char in temp_string:
                                a=temp_string.find(char)
                                score['Kevin']+=1
                                temp_string = ''.join(list(temp_string).pop(a))
                            
                    elif char[0] in consonant:
                        #logic goes here
                        for i in range(len(temp_string)):
                            if char in temp_string:
                                a=temp_string.find(char)
                                score['Stuart']+=1
                                temp_string = ''.join(list(temp_string).pop(a))
    #Test string
    #print(score)
    #Winner Selection
    if score['Kevin']>score['Stuart']:
        print("Kevin "+ str(score['Kevin']))
    elif score['Kevin']==score['Stuart']:
        print("Draw")
    else:
        print("Stuart "+ str(score['Stuart']))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = input()
    minion_game(s)
```

This codes runs fine the only problem i observe is the time complexity which I'm not able to solve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number of substrings with a fixed starting point is just the length of the remaining string. Also you might want to use the string module a bit + some literals instead of ord. Additionally membership lookup is much faster in sets than lists. You can use these to simplify things down a lot:

```
import string


VOWELS = set('aeiouAEIOU')
CONSONANTS = set(string.ascii_letters) - VOWELS

def new_minion_game(s):
    total_len = len(s)
    kevin = 0
    stuart = 0
    for index, character in enumerate(s):
        if character in VOWELS:
            kevin += total_len - index
        elif character in CONSONANTS:
            stuart += total_len - index
    return kevin, stuart
```

On my system this was approx. 200x faster.